# Capture file name of phonegap file upload - phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

i'm making a photo upload system with phonegap. i have the below script which does uploads correctly. Now what i'm trying to achieve is to save the filename of the photo to a hidden field so i can have it to insert into my database. I have a working php insertion script, but now my problem is how to capture the value of the file field into a hidden field or textfield so i can do the upload

```
</script>        
    function selectPhoto() {

        // Retrieve image file location from specified source
        navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto,
        function(message) { alert('get picture failed'); },
        { quality: 50, 
        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY, }
        );

    }

    function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

        var params = new Object();
        params.value1 = "test";
        params.value2 = "param";

        options.params = params;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, "http://some.server.com/upload.php", win, fail, options);
    }

    function win(r) {
        console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
        console.log("Response = " + r.response);
        console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
    }

    function fail(error) {
        alert("An error has occurred: Code = " = error.code);
        console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
        console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use localStorage to store data in HTML5. Using localStorage you can retrieve and pass data on any HTML5 page.

Link to localStorage docs.: [Cordova localStorage](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_storage_localstorage_localstorage.md.html)

First retrieve file name from javascript variable `options.fileName` and store it in localStorage and later send it using AJAX.

ex. `window.localStorage.setItem("key", "options.fileName");`

and get it `var fileName = window.localStorage.getItem("key");`

Or else you can send it in Multipart form submission as it is shown in above example and retrieve it in PHP

```
$image = "$_FILES["file"]["name"].'.jpg';
```